# if $a$ is a real root of any quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb D$, then $a\in \mathbb D$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> $\mathbb D$ is the set of real numbers such that $a\in \mathbb D$ iff the point $(a,0)$ is constructible. Prove that if $a$ is a real root of any quadratic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb D$, then $a\in \mathbb D$.

I have proven that $\mathbb D$ is a field with respect to taking square roots of positive numbers. So I figured I would find the root to some polynomial using square roots but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is a root of $x^2+px+q$ (it's not restrictive to assume the polynomial is monic), then, by the quadratic formula,
$$
a=\frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}
$$
and $p^2-4q\ge0$ by assumption. Since $\mathbb{D}$ is a field closed under taking square roots (of positive elements), we are done.